# Как получить 3 разных записи с одного поля?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблицы:

table1

```
id, name, type, value  
1 name1 type1 1  
1 name1 type2 2  
1 name1 type3 3  
2 name2 type2 2  
3 name3 type3 3
```

Как мне в запросе получить данные таким образом?

```
id, name, type1, type2,type3  
1 name1 1 2 3  
2 name2 null 2 null
```

Comment: `group by name` какой-нибудь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В MySQL нет PIVOT, так что типа

```
SELECT id, name,
MAX(CASE type WHEN 'type1' THEN value END) type1,
MAX(CASE type WHEN 'type2' THEN value END) type2,
MAX(CASE type WHEN 'type3' THEN value END) type3
FROM table1
GROUP BY id, name
```