# Выборка из двух таблиц базы данных mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Eсть 2 таблицы в БД:
users

```
+----+-------+-------------+
| id | name  |   lastname  |
+----+-------+-------------+
|  1 | Иван  |   Иванов    |
|  2 | Петр  |   Петров    |
+----+-------+-------------+
```

users_info

```
+----+-------+-------+---------+
| id | user  | field | data    |
+----+-------+-----------------+
|  1 | 2     | 1     | Петрович|
|  2 | 1     | 1     | Иванович|
|  3 | 1     | 3     | +791398 |
|  4 | 1     | 4     | Москва  |
|  5 | 2     | 4     | Питер   |
|  6 | 2     | 3     | 892641  |
+----+-------+-------+---------+
```

Как можно получить значения в таком виде:

```
1 Иванов Иван Иванович +791398 Москва
2 Петров Петро Петрович 892641 Питер
```

Можно ли это сделать в mysql?
я делаю так:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, u.firstname, u.lastname, l.data, l.fieldid
        FROM mdl_user as u
            LEFT JOIN mdl_user_info_data AS l on u.id = l.userid
```

Но получаю:

```
1 Иван Иванов +791398
1 Иван Иванов Москва
1 Иван Иванов Иванович
2 Петр Петров 892641
2 Петр Петров Питер
2 Петр Петров Петрович
```

Запрос делаю в mysql и обрабатываю php. Или в php  уже как-то склеить их?

Comment: Если количество результирующих колонок заранее известно, то можно применять что то вроде этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/690405/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-3-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f/690408#690408  Если нет, то проще в php собрать

Comment: а как это собрать в php можно?

Comment: чем пользуетесь, mysqli или PDO ?

Comment: В предложенных таблицах не вижу полей username и firstname? остальное при помощи группировки записей и уже потом в php.

Comment: такая структура называется EAV, можшь погуглить. Например вот [mariadb пишет](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/entity-attribute-value-implementation/) что этот вариант так себе. и лучше телефон и отчество вынести в сделать нормальными колонками в таблице юзерс, а всякую дребедень, типа любимого цвета - положить туда же в юзерс в джейсон

Comment: Изначально структура базы данных корявая, либо кто-то просто в качестве учебного примера написал первое, что пришло в голову.

Comment: @MaxRaskolnikov такая структура называется EAV, можшь погуглить. Если для хранения разнородных характеристик придумаешь чисто реляционное решение лучше - можешь претендовать на какую-нибудь премию

Comment: @Ипатьев Нужна ли EAV для такой ерундовой базы? Зачем микроскопом гвозди забивать? В вопросе нет указания на EAV, это ваши домыслы. Правильная изначально структура БД предотвращает многие проблемы.

Comment: @MaxRaskolnikov я просто умею вопросы читать :)

Comment: @Ипатьев Больше похоже на то, что вы хотите либо напугать Виктора, либо сделать его, в итоге, гуру SQL :)))

Comment: @MaxRaskolnikov да нет. просто я действительно умею читать вопросы. я очень давно этим занимаюсь. В вопросе видно что пример данных дан от балды, и там никакие не отчества и телефоны. EAV  "в качестве учебного примера" не делают. До него ещё дойти нужно. А здесь даже имя свойства нормализовано. Но не буду спорить, возможен и такой вариант что автору поможет переписать тупо на линейную таблицу

Comment: если я правильно понял users_info у вас в поле user = id из users, field = перечисление значения в data. сделайте еще n-раз left join только таблицы делайте с where field=1, where field=2 ... и получите "транспонированную" таблицу по одному полю.

Comment: SELECT u.id, u.username, u.firstname, u.lastname, u1.data as second_name, u3.data as phone, u4.data as city 
        FROM users
            LEFT JOIN users_info AS u1 on users.id = u1.userid and u1.field=1
   LEFT JOIN users_info AS u2 on users.id = u2.userid and u2.field=2
   LEFT JOIN users_info AS u3 on users.id = u3.userid and u3.field=3
только еще добавить гроуп бай по виртуальной таблице.

Comment: Проблема в том, что структура данной  бд - данность, ее уже не поменять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться следующим запросом:

```
SELECT 
    users.*,
    middle_name.data as middle_name,
    phone.data as phone,
    city.data as city
FROM users
LEFT JOIN users_info as middle_name ON middle_name.user = users.id and middle_name.field=1
LEFT JOIN users_info as phone ON phone.user = users.id and phone.field=3
LEFT JOIN users_info as city ON city.user = users.id and city.field=4

;
```

Проверить запрос на [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=22906bdbe7efb80ec07677b23fb2b06c&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

В запросе испльзуется многократное соединение таблицы с различными условиями и алиасами

Другой подход pivot для таблицы users_info и соединение с таблицей usrs:

```
SELECT 
    users.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field=1, data, null)) as middle_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field=3, data, null)) as phone,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field=4, data, null)) as city
FROM users_info
JOIN users ON users.id = users_info.user
GROUP BY user, users.id, users.name, users.lastname;
```

Пример [здесь](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=309b452e126b8f742da8d344ee10ff73&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)